# How can I set a toolbar style to both_horiz?

Tags: java, gtk, gnome

I am using java-gnome (Ubuntu 11.04, libjava-gnome-java 4.0.11) and am trying to set my `Toolbar.setStyle(ToolbarStyle.BOTH_HORIZ);` (which should show the icon and text from a stock item side by side) but it will not show text next to the icon. I was also seeing that `Button`s with stock items were only showing the icon, even if I explicitly set the label for the `Button`. Only if I do not set a Stock item does the label show up. If I do `ToolbarStyle.TEXT` it shows the test, if I use `ToolbarStyle.BOTH` it shows the icon over the text, but `ToolbarStyle.BOTH_HORIZ` or leaving it blank (both_horiz is default in gnome) it just shows the icon.

I looked at some other GTK applications (not java-gnome) on my computer and they have both_horiz working correctly, and I have it set as default in gconf (`/desktop/gnome/interface/toolbar_style`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the tool item to be "important", otherwise the label will not show in both_horiz mode. Use [`ToolItem.setIsImportant()`](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/gtk/ToolItem.html#setIsImportant%28boolean%29).

Comment: No, the use case for both_horiz mode is to save space. I could imagine, though, that it might be useful to display the non-important labels if the window is big enough, and only hide them when space is needed.